# Redirect the output of a for loop in cmd.exe

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd, pipe

What I want to do is this:

`(for %%a in ('command') DO something) | anothercommand`

Unfortunately cmd.exe parses parentheses like this:

```
v open                v close
(for %%a in ('command') DO something) | anothercommand
```

If I don't use parentheses around `for`, then the `anothercommand` is treated as if it was in the `DO` block.

This forces me to output the result of each `DO` block iteration
to a temporary file and then read it again:

```
for %%a in ('command') DO echo %%a >> file.txt
anothercommand < file.txt
```

I'm looking for a cleaner solution that doesn't bottleneck itself because of writing and reading from storage.

Comment: Try to aggregate the piping as common block:  **for %%a in ('command') DO (something | anothercommand )**

Comment: `(for /F "tokens=3,5 delims= " %%a IN ('find "%CONTINENT%" Covid.txt') DO if %%a equ %MONTH% echo %%b) | anothercommand`
is what I'm having trouble with specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, cmd.exe does NOT close the first parenthesis after your command.
There is another problem in your code.

Working example:

```
( FOR /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir') do @echo ##File: %%A ) | findstr /N "^"
```

But the main problem of piping is, that both sides are executed in a new sub cmd.exe instance.
And there it's running in the command line context, not batch file context.
Therefore the syntax changes a bit, and it's necessary to add the `@` in front of `echo` to avoid the debug output.